# I have delete my some file from my project and now it don't show my project in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in iOS. When I delete some file from my project it don't show project how can I recover my project.

[image]

Please give me solution. can anybody face this problem. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Close xcode and reopen.

Comment: try to put back that files from your trash

Comment: Which files? Was it the `project.pbxproj`?

Comment: @Nicholas Smith its project..xcworkspace

Comment: U deleted project..xcworkspace?

Comment: It Shows me all file. But not accessable in Xcode.

Comment: @Muju: try running `pod install` again.

Comment: First try to quit xcode and reopen project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Finder > All My Files >serach file name

Comment: I am also facing this problem in my app, i solving this type. i think it is use  for you

Comment: thank you. Now it give me error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: $(inherited) add in other linker flags

Comment: But I am not able to open it from my folder.

Comment: that file drag and drop to your app.

Comment: u got it for lost last question aswer.

Comment: I got my files thanks for that.But it shows an error.

Comment: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125167/discussion-between-siva-sankar-and-muju).